# Ark PS4 server INI files

Tags: discussion

Is this the right place to ask for help with my game server's ini file settings and such?

Comment: Hi Joey, I've migrated your question to our Meta site, where we host questions that are about the site itself and how to use & improve it.

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming that by "Ark" in the title, you mean the released game [ARK: Survival Evolved](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ark:_Survival_Evolved) / Survival of the Fittest.

If that's correct, then **no, this is not the site on which to ask how to configure your ARK server**. Questions about playing existing, released games should be asked on [our game-playing sister site Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com).

Be sure to [check through their existing catalogue of Q&A about configuring ARK servers](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=server%20%5Bark-survival-evolved%5D) to see if your question has already been answered.

---

GameDev.StackEchange is a site for **game developers designing and building their own original games and game mods**. So if you have questions about developing and configuring a server for a new game that you're creating, then that would most likely be on-topic here.